# calculating the center of mass of a set of vectors (during a proof of a Hilbert polynomial identity)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, multivalued-functions, multivariate-polynomial

I was reading Hilbert's proof of the Hilbert-Waring theorem in [this](https://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/MATH140/2009-10%20(A.%20%CE%93%CE%B9%CE%B1%CE%BD%CE%BD%CF%8C%CF%80%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82)/%CE%86%CF%81%CE%B8%CF%81%CE%B1%20%CE%B5%CF%80%CE%B9%CF%83%CE%BA%CF%8C%CF%80%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%B7%CF%82/ellison.pdf) survey paper, and came across the following statement in page 25, which i rephrased a little, regarding the center of mass of a set of vectors, in the real vector space $V$ of homogeneous polynomials of degree 2k in 5 variables:

> Let $T$ be the set of vectors in $V$ given by the forms $L=$($\alpha_{1}x_{1}+  ... +\alpha_{5}x_{5})^{2k}$ with $\alpha_{i}\in$R and $\alpha_{1}^{2}+ ... +\alpha_{5}^{2}\leq1.$ Then the center of gravity of the mass distribution of unit density throughout $T$ and zero elsewhere is given by $\\$:
>   $\displaystyle g = \left. \int_{R}(\alpha_{1}x_{1}+  ... +\alpha_{5}x_{5})^{2k}d\alpha_{1}...d\alpha_{5} \middle/ \int_{R}d\alpha_{1}...d\alpha_{5}  \right.\\       $
>   where $R$ is the region in $R^{5}$ defined by $\alpha_{1}^{2}+ ... +\alpha_{5}^{2}\leq1$

I don't understand how this calculation in $R^{5}$ will give us the desired center of mass in the vector space $V$, any help would be appriciated!